# Unity crash and network adapters missing after uninstalling virtualbox

Tags: networking, unity, wireless, drivers, virtualbox

While trying to remove VirtualBox install the latest version on Ubuntu 14.04, Unity crashed and is now refusing to load properly (no sidebar, taskbar, keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ...etc).

To make matters worse, I can't attempt to fix the problem because it seems the network drivers  no longer work; that is I no longer have the `wlan0` adapter or any `eth` adapters showing, and not even sure it's registering the wireless card anymore.

Anyone with experience of this particular issue?

Comment: Start from looking into `/var/log/dpkg.log` to see what was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not related to the uninstall of virtualbox at all- I had tried to (and forgotten about) install a newer version of virtualbox after the uninstall and mistakenly downloaded the 32-bit version. Installing that on my 64-bit system is what killed it- and it turned out to be easier to wipe everything and start over for me but perhaps someone else could come up with a fix.